# Where to add management certificate for SAP HANA Trial activation on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, hana

I want to add management certificate which is downloaded by SAP websites itself and has to upload it on Microsoft Azure portal to activation. I know that it should be uploaded in settings tab on Azure portal, but I am not getting path for settings.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the old Azure portal to upload the certificate.
https://manage.windowsazure.com